# amp-bind Error: Default value for [variable] does not match first expression result

Tags: google-amp, amp-bind

I am using `amp-bind` to bind the class attribute:

```
<div [class]="menu.menuClass" class=hide">...</div>
```

with the following `amp-state` element:

```
<amp-state id="menu">
  <script type="application/json">
  {"menuClass":"hide"}
  </script>
</amp-state>
```

However, after the page loads, I get the error:

```
amp-bind: Default value for [class] does not match first expression result (hide). This can result in unexpected behavior after the next state change.&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;
```

(this error is empedded in the `div` itself)

As you can see, my default value does match the first expression. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, this is a bug! :) I've filed [this issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/8716) and we're working on a fix.

We try to keep an eye on StackOverflow but feel free to file an issue in our [GitHub project](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml) or ask a question on our [Slack channel](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#ongoing-participation) next time. Thanks for raising this, Gil.